# Путь к изображению Java

Tags: java, path

Здравствуйте! Есть игра на Java, с использованием картинок.

**Импорт картинки**

```
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new File("images\\stand.png"));
    this.setOpaque(false);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Неверный путь к изображению.");
}
```

Когда запускаю главный класс из Intellij Idea все работает,но когда компилирую все в единый JAR файл, то "Неверный путь к изображению.". Как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В том же каталоге, из которого вы запускаете jar-файл, разве есть каталог `src`? Лучше сложить изображения в  `resources\images` и извлекать с помощью `getResource()`.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman перед тем, как рассказывать про получение доступа к файлу внутри jar надо бы еще рассказать что это вообще такое...

Comment: @PavelMayorov тут есть ответ и на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/PlemGitHub/GoodClassesToUse/blob/master/ImageImport.java

`"/Cards/"+imageName+".png"` значит файл лежит в Your_project_name\src\Cards\imageName.png

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло